# Discord.js (v13) SlashCommandBuilder addIntegerOption set Range

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to write a slash command that clears messages. Everything is fine, but there one thing I couldn't really figure out:

How would I set the range for an integer option in a slash command build, or is there even something like this or do I need to do the old-school way and response that the value is out of range?

Here is my data for the slash command that will be registered:

```js
data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('clear')
        .setDescription('Clears specified amount of Messages')
        .addIntegerOption(option => {
            option
            .setName('amount')
            .setRequired(true)
            .setDescription('The Amount of Messages to clear')
        }),
```

Comment: I don't think you can set the range, I believe you have to handle that in your callback (check if it's bigger than max or smaller than min)

Comment: thx for fixing my writing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly there Is no option to set the range, but there a new thing called ephemeral that you can use as a setting in interaction.reply()

example:

```js
interaction.reply({ content: "Your amount is bigger than 500", ephemeral: true"})
```

[image: result]

ephemeral lets only the user of the command see the reply and he can simply delete it if he wants through pressing the blue text wich says "Nachricht verferfen" in my case because my Discord is set to German.

**Edit**
I have to correct Myself there is actually an Option for min and max for integer options and for some other options like string options you actually can write your own autocompletion

Comment: Do you know if this is on the DDevs' radar at all?

Comment: this sadly has nothing to do with discord.js itself, but its a thing with the discord api itself, discord.js cant implement something that discord itself doesn't have :)

Answer (score 4):

As Snoweuph has already stated, their answer is incorrect — you are able to [set minimum](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandIntegerOption?scrollTo=setMinValue) and [maximum](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandIntegerOption?scrollTo=setMaxValue) values using `setMinValue()` and `setMaxValue()`.

Here's what that looks like in code:

```js
data = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("example")
    .setDescription("wow look at me!")
    .addIntegerOption(option =>
        option.setName("integer")
            .setDescription("some name i guess")
            .setMinValue(0)
            .setMaxValue(22)
    );
```

And in Discord, the user will receive an error message if the integer they chose is too large or too small.

Example Discord chat log here:

[image]

This also works with Number options ([docs](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandNumberOption?scrollTo=setMaxValue)).